# How to stub current_user in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest, sorcery

How do I stub `current_user` in Rails 5?

I expected this:

```
@controller.stub :current_user, mock_user do

end
```

to work, but there is no `@controller` in `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`? I use `sorcery` gem for authentication.

Comment: What is `current_user`? Is it a variable ? A method? Do you use devise?

Comment: It's a method on a controller. I use sorcery. I'll put that in question, I didn't find it important since most auth gems define it.

Comment: Can you show us the inside of the block and the output of any errors/failures you're getting?

Comment: @Glyoko inside of the block is not relevant, and, most likely, will only be `yield` anyway. The error is, as I have written, that instance variable `@controller` does not exist in `IntegrationTest` (controller testing changed a bit in Rails 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [wiki example](https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery/wiki/Testing-Rails):

```
class TeamsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Integration
  include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Controller

  setup do
    @team = teams(:one)
    @user = users(:one)

    login_user(user = @user, route = login_url)  # replace with your login url path
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:teams)
  end
```

That will set your test user as `current_user`.